# 2007 KOW VULCAN 800 LOST COMPRESSION

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, compression

I have an '07 kow vulcan only 6k miles and recently rebuilt carb., now it is losing compression and is killing me to speed up even in low gear, could the clutch plates be shot even at this low mileage?

Comment: have you _tested_ the compression?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What does compression have to do with the clutch plates? They are completely unrelated. I have a feeling something is going on with your bike and you're guessing at what you think it might be. Why don't you explain what's going on, in complete detail. Don't tell us what you *think* is going wrong, tell us what is happening when you ride your bike. We're here to help, but we can only help when you give us information without supposition.

Comment: If the clutch is worn out, the engine will rev fine, but the bike won't accelerate.

Comment: How did you test the compression? What was the result? Has a setting slipped in the carb - since you mention that as previous work?